# curve between two points having maximum area

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the curve(i.e. the segment of a standard curve like circle, ellipse etc.) amongst all curves(segments) that have  fixed total length, passes through $ (a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ and has maximum area between itself and the line joining the two points.
I think calculus of variations is the way, but what is the functional to be extremized? Also whether double integrals have a role to play?

Comment: duplicate - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834585/curve-enclosing-the-maximum-area?noredirect=1#comment3750653_1834585 - please don't post same questions twice

Comment: What area should be maximazed?

Comment: @gt6989b thanks. I modified the question slightly

Comment: Is this a _closed_ curve?  As the question stands right now, there is no specification of a boundary for an "area".  (This differs from the "duplicate" linked, as that question used the $ \ x-$ axis as part of the boundary, and a curve segment passing through the indicated points for the rest.)

Comment: I think the answer is circle and is a direct consequence of the isoperimetric problem.

Comment: It's definitely a circle: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/isop.shtml

Answer (score 1):

If $y=f(x)$ is the equation of the curve, the functional to be extremized (supposing $a<c$) is the one giving the area between the curve and the straight line:
$$
\int_a^c \left(f(x)-{d-b\over c-a}(x-a)+b\right)dx,
$$
with the constraint:
$$
\int_a^c \sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}\,dx=l.
$$